# Proving That Even Potential Leads to Even or Odd Wavefunction

Tags: functions, physics

if the potential $V(x)=V(-x)$ (is even), then $\psi(x)$ can be taken as even or odd

$\displaystyle -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{d^{2}\psi(x)}{dx^{2}}+V(x)\psi(x)=E\psi(x)$ is the same as $\displaystyle -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{d^{2}\psi(-x)}{dx^{2}}+V(x)\psi(-x)=E\psi(-x)$

linear combinations for even: $\psi(x) + \psi(-x)$ = even
                    for odd $\psi(x) - \psi(-x)$ = odd

from now on I get confused, suppose we have a solution $\psi$ as an odd function, does that mean it could get minus value, but than $E\psi(-x)=-E\psi(-x)$ and this is nonsense.

mathematically no matter what funcion you insert you get the same result as stated before, but intuitively I am lost here ;]

Another part what if function is nor even nor odd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wavefunction $\psi$ generally takes complex values, so it's not immediately clear what a "minus" value would be – do you mean a negative real value? If so: Yes, any wavefunction, not just an even or odd one, can take negative real values. Since you can multiply any solution of the Schrödinger equation by an arbitrary phase factor, you can make it take negative real values wherever you like. It's not clear to me why you write that this implies $E\psi(-x)=-E\psi(-x)$.

As to the second part of your question: There may indeed be a solution that is neither even, nor odd (this would be called an "accidental degeneracy"). In this case you can take the linear combinations that you described, $\psi(x)+\psi(-x)$ and $\psi(x)-\psi(-x)$, to obtain an even solution and an odd solution.

Comment: my mistake, I assumed  that odd function automatically gives you negative result

Comment: @scsi: An odd wavefunction, like any wavefunction, can be multiplied by an arbitrary complex phase factor (and still remains odd), so you can let it have any values you like (phasewise).

Comment: about the second part does that mean if i have a genral solution i could express it like that $\Psi (x)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_{n}\psi _n(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_{n}(\psi_{n+}(x)+\psi_{n-}(x)) $

Comment: @scsi: I guess you're implying that the $\psi_n$, $\psi_{n+}$, $\psi_{n-}$ are all solutions of the Schrödinger equation (otherwise the statement would be trivial). Yes, you can do that, but note that the case where the energies of an even and an odd solution coincide (so they can be linearly combined to get a non-symmetric solution) is an exception (a degeneracy) -- the more typical case is that the solutions are all either even or odd, with different energies.

Comment: Thank you for your time! just took my first step in QM.

Answer (score 0):

If $\psi(x)$ is odd, then replace $\psi(x)$ by $\psi(-x)=-\psi(x)$.
All three terms - both the terms on the left, and the term on the right - change sign.
That makes $\psi(-x)$ obey the same equation that $\psi(x)$ did.